# Shiny dygraphs - Eliminate Time Series Offset

Tags: shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to graph two time series charts on the same `dygraphOutput`, but the data set was recorded on different dates and at different times.  The date and time are not important, so they can be on the same scale.

But I am not sure how to modify the time series in my `xts` object to be the same across both of my data sets.

The alternative would be for me to not use a time series (since the date and time aren't important.)  Could I use `ggplot2` instead to plot these on a traditional line chart, and just have my x-axis as the scan # from my data logger?

Comment: You can index the two series yourself and not use the time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can you elaborate on what type of command I'd run to index these series?